# .join() works in one example but not the other

Tags: javascript

Just a quick question for the following example of reversing a string.

In the first example this works fine:

```js
let name = ['j', 'o', 'e'].reverse().join('');
console.log(name);
```

But in this second example join doesn't work and name remains an array. I'm not sure why.

```js
let name = ['j', 'o', 'e'];
name.reverse();
name.join('');
console.log(name);
```

Comment: because join returns a string, it does not change the original variable. `let foo = name.join('');`

Comment: @LearningEveryday not sure how that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) returns a string and you need an assignment for keeping the value.

[`Array#reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) woprks in situ and mutates the array.

BTW, [`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) is a property of `window` and keeps the name of the window.

```js
let value = ['j', 'o', 'e'];
value.reverse();
value = value.join('');

console.log(value);
```